# accessing command line arguments for headless NetLogo in the Matlab extension

Tags: matlab, netlogo

I'm running the matlab extension for netlogo in headless(non-gui) mode.  I've downloded the extension source and am trying to access the command line arguments from the java code in the extension.  The command line arguments are stored in LabInterface.Settings.  I would like to be able to access that object in the java code of the extension.  I've been working on this for a couple of days but have had not success.  It seems the extension process is designed to create primitives to be used inside netlogo.  These primitives have knowledge of the different netlogo objects but there is no way for the extension java code to access it.  I would appreciate any help.

I would like to be able to run multiple netlogo-matlab analyses with varying parameters, in batch mode accross multiple machines, perhaps a flux cluster. I need to run in headless because of the batch nature. Sometimes the runs will be on the same machine, sometimes split accross multiple machines, flux or condor. I know a similar functionality exist in netlogo for running varying parameters in a single session. Is there some way to split these accross multiple machines?

Currently, I create a series of setup files for netlogo. Each setup file represents the paramenters that vary for that run. Then I submit each netlogo - setup file combination as a single run. Each run can be farmed out to a seperate machine or processor. Adding the matlab extension complicates this. The matlab extension connects it's server to port 9999. With multiple servers running they all get attached to port 9999 and this causes problems. I was hoping to get information from the setup-file name to create independent port numbers tied to the setup file names. This way I could create a unique socket for each setup file, and hence a unique server connection for each netlogo run.

Comment: What's the use case for this? As in, what are you actually trying to accomplish? The Settings object isn't stored anywhere, just handed off from method to method, so I think you may need to consider alternate approaches.

Comment: also asked at http://netlogo-users.18673.x6.nabble.com/accessing-headless-setup-information-from-matlab-extension-td5004795.html

Comment: I'll probably try an alternate approach with sub-directories.

Answer (score 0):

NetLogo doesn't provide a facility for distributing model runs on a cluster, but various people have done it anyway. See:

- http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/faq.html#cluster
- https://github.com/jurnix/netlogo-cluster
- http://mass.aitia.ai/index.php/intro/meme

and past threads about it on the netlogo-users group. There is no single standard solution.

As for getting access to LabInterface.Settings, it appears to me from looking through the NetLogo source code that the settings object isn't actually stored anywhere. It's just handed off from method to method, ultimately to `lab.Lab.run`, without ever actually being kept.  So trying to get access to the name of the setup file won't work.

So you'll need to some other way for to make the extension generate unique port numbers. Seems to me like there's any number of possible solutions to this. At the time you generate the setup file you know its name, so you could generate a port number at the same time and include it in the experiment definition contained in the file. Or you could pass a port number in a Java system property (using `-D`) at the time you start NetLogo. Or you could generate a port number based on the process id of the JVM process. Or you could have the extension try port 9999 and see if it's already in use, and if it is, then try a different port number. That's just a few ideas... I could probably come up with ten more.

Comment: Hi when I whant to run netlogo on a cluster, I'm using openmole ... http://www.openmole.org/ it's so nice !